# Select only the clicked button JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this ajax function, which should change the style of the clicked button, but for some reason it does not work. I'm not getting any errors in the console and the ajax call is successful Any idea what's wrong here?

```
function AcceptOffer(id)
{
    var json = {
        id : id
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("AcceptOffer", "Product")",
        dataType : "json",
        data: {"json": JSON.stringify(json)},
        success: function() {
            $(this).text("Accepted");
            $(this).css("background-color", "green");
            $(this).css("color", "white");
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);

        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('Some error');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="AcceptOffer('@item.OfferId')" class="btn btn-default acceptbtn">Accept</a>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and the code that sets up the `click` event handler for the button. Also, `this` within the `success` function most likely doesn't reference the `button`. Have you tried adding `console.log(this);` in the `success` callback to see?

Comment: Well, first, you should not be using a hyperlink for anything other than navigation. Just about any visual element supports the `click` event and you should probably just use a `button` to kick off some code. Also,  you should not be using inline event attributes like `onclick` and instead use the modern standard of  `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yeah... `console.log(this)` just prints random stuff, it does not have a reference to the anchor tag

Comment: Well there you go. You aren't referencing the right element. What does it print? Additionally, since you currently are using a hyperlink, know that hyperlinks don't have a `disabled` attribute.

Comment: You should probably just reference the element directly instead of using `this`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus any idea on how to do this if i have more than one anchor tag with the same class?

Comment: There are several ways... You could find it based on its relative position to some other element, you could find it based on an `id`, you could find it by its numerical index of all similar elements, you could also just give it an additional class that other elements don't have. But again, you shouldn't be using anchors for this in the first place.

Comment: @ScottMarcus just so I don't use `a` tags next time, what would be the most suitable tag for these cases?

Comment: As I mentioned, the `button` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with using `this` incorrectly. The way you are using it, it is going to reference the object you pass into the ajax command

```
function AcceptOffer(id)
{
    var json = {
        id : id
    };

    var elemYouWantToChange =...;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("AcceptOffer", "Product")",
        dataType : "json",
        data: {"json": JSON.stringify(json)},
        success: function() {
            $(elemYouWantToChange).text("Accepted");
            $(elemYouWantToChange).css("background-color", "green");
            $(elemYouWantToChange).css("color", "white");
            $(elemYouWantToChange).attr('disabled', true);

        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('Some error');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

-- Edit --

In javascript, you listen for a click like so:

```
elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target); // You need to get e.target to AcceptOffer so it can style the correct element
  AcceptOffer(...);
});
```

Comment: yeah, but I have a lot of elements with the same class attribute and they all change. I just want to select the one i click.

Comment: Pass the event to `AcceptOffer(id,e)` and then use `e.target`.

Comment: @EL02 I was just updating my answer to demonstrate what user1599011 is saying

Comment: In your code `elemYouWantToChange` should = `e.target`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `this` is not pointing to the anchor tag you just need to pass `this` reference to your function.

```
function AcceptOffer(ele, id)
{
var json = {
    id : id
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "@Url.Action("AcceptOffer", "Product")",
    dataType : "json",
    data: {"json": JSON.stringify(json)},
    success: function() {
        $(ele).text("Accepted");
        $(ele).css("background-color", "green");
        $(ele).css("color", "white");
        $(ele).attr('disabled', true);

    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('Some error');
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
}
```

So the anchor tag will be:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="AcceptOffer(this, '@item.OfferId')" class="btn btn-default acceptbtn">Accept</a>
```

Comment: Or inside the function, just set `ele` to `e.target` and then you don't have to pass `this` at all.